# React-bootstrap styling showing up before finished api call

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am making a small application in React that fetches a random image using Axios. I am using React-bootstrap to style the image, however a small white box is displayed for half of a second before the image is done loading. How can I resolve this?

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Image, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';


const ROOT_URL = 'myurl'

export default class WhatDog extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = { randomImg: '' };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get(ROOT_URL)
    .then(res => {
      const data = res.data.message
      this.setState({ randomImg: data })
    })
  }

  renderImage(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Image src={this.state.randomImg} className="img" thumbnail/>
        <Link to="/">
          <Button bsStyle="danger" bsSize="large">Go back</Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    )
  }



  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
          {
            (this.state.randomImg === '')
            ? <div>
                <h1>Loading...</h1>
              </div>

            : <div>
                {this.renderImage()}
              </div>
          }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you don't see the **Loading...**?

Comment: I see the loading, but I also see the small empty white box under it.

Comment: the image needs some time till it's actually complete loaded by the browser..

Comment: It might be difficult to determine why the styling on the image is weird without seeing the code that actually renders the image. Could you maybe with the source for your Image class? The code you have provided doesn't appear to have any issues as far as I can see

Comment: Should I add a setTimeout to the renderImage function?

Comment: It would be good practice to set during the loading phase to have a spinner (like from FontAwesome) which could be unset after all of your data is fetched.

Comment: I wouldn't add a setTimeout no.

Comment: setTimeout will not help.. the image will start loading after you rendered the img tag...

Comment: using the `onLoad` event might help, see my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will fire the `onLoad` event, after the image has been, you name it.. `loaded` so before that, set the `visibility` to hidden.. NOT `display: none` ! Because `display: none` will also prevent the loading.

The solution might look something like this

```
<Image
  src={this.state.randomImg}
  style={!this.state.imgVisible ? {visibility: 'hidden'} : {}}
  onLoad={() => this.setState({ imgVisible: true })}
/>
```

Note: This is using inline styles and arrow functions, which is not best, but for simplicity of the demo its enough, you could also you a className instead, its up to you ;)

You got the idea...

Comment: It worked! Only thing I changed is "styles" to "style." Thanks, pal. ;)

Comment: also note, when you change the image, you will have to set `imgVisible` again to `false`